# Как внутри <?if (!isset($_COOKIE[сюда])){?> вставить php echo

Tags: php

Подскажите, как внутри `<?if (!isset($_COOKIE[сюда надо вставить])){?>` вставить вот такой код: `<?php echo $this->href_to('karma_vote', $profile['id']); ?>` Такая конструкция нужна для того, чтобы в $_COOKIE[] на каждой странце был уникальный код, который в другом месте этой страницы выводится с помощью `<?php echo $this->href_to('karma_vote', $profile['id']); ?>`. Если вставлять как есть - страница не открывается, ошибка 500. Наверное, решение на уровне азов PHP, но я как раз решил постигать их опытным путем и пока не могу сам найти рабочий способ.

Comment: Ты хочешь сделать какую-то ерунду. Лучше **а)** Хотя бы прочитай хотя бы одну книгу по  PHP  **б)** посиди долго и внимательно составь корректный вопрос о том, что ты на самом деле хочешь сделать в целом и зачем оно надо. И получи правильный ответ, а не непонятный костыльный совет на свои пожелания видеть кривокод

Comment: А так, скорее всего ты хочешь `$_COOKIE[$this->href_to('karma_vote', $profile['id'])]`, но это не точно

Answer (score 0):

Задать значение для определенного параметра (ключа) в cookie можно следующим образом:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['karma_vote'])) {
  $karmaVote = $this->href_to('karma_vote', $profile['id']);

  setcookie('karma_vote', $karmaVote);
} else {
  echo $_COOKIE['karma_vote'];
}
```

`karma_vote` - это ключ (можно указать любое другое название), для которого вы записываете нужное значение и храните в cookie.

С помощью `isset()` проверяете, содержится ли в cookie значение для этого ключа.

Если там ничего нет, то получаете значение из вашего метода `href_to()` и записываете для `karma_vote` с помощью [setcookie()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php).

При необходимости, выстраиваете дополнительные [параметры](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php#refsect1-function.setcookie-parameters).

Если в `$_COOKIE['karma_vote']` уже содержится какое-либо значение, то оно будет выведено на экран с помощью `echo`.